# Efficient way of using two directives at the same time in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm new to Angular 2 and here is my code

```
<ng-container *ngIf="pageOrSearch"> 
    <div *ngFor="let feed of feedsPage">
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Title: </u></font><strong>{{feed.title}}</strong><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>PubDate: </u></font>{{feed.pubDate}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Link: </u></font><a target="_blank" href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.link}}</a><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Description: </u></font>{{feed.description}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Category: </u></font>{{feed.category}}<hr>
     </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-container *ngIf="!pageOrSearch"> 
     <div *ngFor="let feed of feeds">
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Title: </u></font><strong>{{feed.title}}</strong><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>PubDate: </u></font>{{feed.pubDate}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Link: </u></font><a target="_blank" href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.link}}</a><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Description: </u></font>{{feed.description}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Category: </u></font>{{feed.category}}<hr>  
     </div>
</ng-container>
```

This works fine, but is there any efficient way of using two directives at the same time in Angular 2? I mean a conditional way of using theese two variables (feedsPage and feeds).

`if pageOrSearch then feedsPage else feeds`.

Comment: Set the variable's value to the right collection in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ternary operator to avoid usage of two directives in one tag, like:

```
<div *ngFor="let feed of (pageOrSearch ? feedsPage : feeds)">
```

Answer (score 0):

simple check the variable in your component first

```
result:any;
if(pageOrSearch){
   this.result=feedsPage;
} else {
   this.result=feeds
}
```

then in your html code:

```
<ng-container> 
     <div *ngFor="let feed of result">
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Title: </u></font><strong>{{feed.title}}</strong><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>PubDate: </u></font>{{feed.pubDate}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Link: </u></font><a target="_blank" href="{{feed.link}}">{{feed.link}}</a><br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Description: </u></font>{{feed.description}}<br>
        <font color="#8b0000"><u>Category: </u></font>{{feed.category}}<hr>  
     </div>
</ng-container>
```